# Add MapBox sourced hillshade to MapBox Studio project

Tags: mapbox, cartocss

I am working on a MapBox studio project that was originally the pre-styled 'OSM Bright 2'.

I have since made lots of edits and would now like to add some subtle hillshading. I can see hillshading is built into some of the other styles like Satellite Afternoon.

How could I include the hillshade source to my OSM Bright 2 style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the docs [here](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-studio/symbol-drawing-order/) under *layer source ordering*.  In short:

Under the **Layers** tab, click the blue **change source** button at the top of the panel.  The modal will give you a list of suggested remote and local sources, as well as listing your existing source(s) as a comma-separated list in the text field at the bottom.

Add the source terrain layer mapId to the beginning of your comma separated list.  The mapId for hillshades is `mapbox.mapbox-terrain-v1` or the newly released `mapbox.mapbox-terrain-v2`.  So, if you're working off of OSM Bright 2, change this:

`mapbox.mapbox-streets-v5`

to:

`mapbox.mapbox-terrain-v1,mapbox.mapbox-streets-v5` or `mapbox.mapbox-terrain-v2,mapbox.mapbox-streets-v5`

For pointers on how to style `mapbox-terrain-v1` checkout any of the example style projects that use it.  For pointers on how to style `mapbox-terrain-v2` check out [this blog post](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/terrain-mapbox-studio/).